# how to stop jquery repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to slide down a list when `mouseenter` the button

```
 $(".topics .goals").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".ligoals").slideDown("slow");
 });
```

and slide up when `mouseleave`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".topics .goals").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".ligoals").slideUp("slow");
  });
});
```

but I have problem so that when I move the mouse fast in and out the button the jquery is keep sliding down and up. I wonder if any one can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events are pushed in a queue. If you move very fast, a lot of animation is enqueue, and is played in the chronological order.

You can use **[.stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)** to avoid this behaviour. Eg below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".topics .goals").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".ligoals").stop(true).slideUp("slow");
  });
  $(".topics .goals").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".ligoals").stop(true).slideDown("slow");
  });
});
```

In general example:

```
$el.event( function(){                
   $(this).stop(true).animate(...);                
});
```